# Plotly: Change y-axis scale

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, data-science, data-analysis

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
    x       y           z
0   Jan     28446000    110489.0    
1   Feb     43267700    227900.0
```

When I plot a line chart like this:

```
px.line(data,x = 'x', y = ['y','z'], line_shape = 'spline', title="My Chart")
```

The y axis scale comes from 0 to 90 M. The first line on the chart for y is good enough. However, the second line appears to be always at 0M. What can I do to improve my chart such that we can see clearly how the values of both column change over the x values?

Is there any way I can normalize the data? Or perhaps I could change the scaling of the chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often times we use data which is in different scales, and scaling the data would mask a characteristic we wish to display. One way to handle this is to add a **secondary y-axis**. An example is shown below.

Key points:

- Create a `layout` dictionary object
- Add a `yaxis2` key to the dict, with the following: `'side': 'right', 'overlaying': 'y1'`

  - This tells Plotly to create a secondary y-axis on the right side of the graph, and to overlay the primary y-axis.
- Assign the appropriate trace to the newly created secondary y-axis as: `'yaxis': 'y2'`

  - The other trace does not need to be assigned, as `'y1'` is the default y-axis.

Comments (TL;DR):
The example code shown here uses the lower-level Plotly API, rather than a convenience wrapper such as `graph_object` to `express`. The reason is that I (personally) feel it's helpful to users to show what is occurring 'under the hood', rather than masking the underlying code logic with a convenience wrapper.

This way, when the user needs to modify a finer detail of the graph, they will have a better understanding of the `list`s and `dict`s which Plotly is constructing for the underlying graphing engine (orca).

The Docs:
Here is a link to the Plotly docs referencing [multiple axes](https://plotly.com/python/multiple-axes/).

#### Example Code:

```
import pandas as pd
from plotly.offline import iplot

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['Jan', 'Feb'],
                   'y': [28446000, 43267700],
                   'z': [110489.0, 227900.0]})

layout = {'title': 'Secondary Y-Axis Demonstration',
          'legend': {'orientation': 'h'}}

traces = []
traces.append({'x': df['x'], 'y': df['y'], 'name': 'Y Values'})
traces.append({'x': df['x'], 'y': df['z'], 'name': 'Z Values', 'yaxis': 'y2'})


# Add config common to all traces.
for t in traces:
    t.update({'line': {'shape': 'spline'}})

layout['yaxis1'] = {'title': 'Y Values', 'range': [0, 50000000]}
layout['yaxis2'] = {'title': 'Z Values', 'side': 'right', 'overlaying': 'y1', 'range': [0, 400000]}


iplot({'data': traces, 'layout': layout})
```

#### Graph:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to change the trace titles in the key at the bottom?

Comment: Yes, of course.  I've edited the code and image to include trace names.  Simply add this key `'name': 'Y Values'` to the `traces.append` statement.  You can title them whatever you like - it's just a string.

Comment: Is it also possible to somehow specify on the y-axis to tell the user which scale/trace falls on which side of the axis?

Comment: Yes, of course.  I've edited the code and image to include y-axis titles. Simply add this key `'title': 'Y Values'` to the `layout['yaxis']` and `layout['yaxis2']` statements.  Here is a link to the [Plotly multi-axis docs](https://plotly.com/python/multiple-axes/) which you might find interesting / helpful.  The `title` key accepts a string, so you can use whatever string value you like. Additionally, HTML is accepted, so this string `'<b>Y Values</b>'` will create a title in **bold**.